# Problema Hibernate 4.3 com Glassfish 3.1

Tags: java, hibernate, glassfish

Minha aplicação com `Hibernate 4.3` roda normalmente com `Glassfish 4`, instalado junto com a IDE `NetBeans`.  Porém, o servidor onde preciso implantar a aplicação, possui o `Glassfish 3.1`.

Neste servidor a aplicação não esta rodando e infelizmente não consigo descobrir o que está ocasionando este erro.

Segue parte de meus códigos:

**glassfish-resources.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE resources PUBLIC "-//GlassFish.org//DTD GlassFish Application Server 3.1 Resource Definitions//EN" "http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-resources_1_5.dtd">
<resources>
    <jdbc-resource enabled="true" jndi-name="jdbc/forcaVendasWeb" object-type="user" pool-name="forcaVendasWebPool">
        <description>Accesses the database that provides data for the ForcaVendasWeb application</description>
    </jdbc-resource>
    <jdbc-connection-pool 
        allow-non-component-callers="false" 
        associate-with-thread="false" 
        connection-creation-retry-attempts="0" 
        connection-creation-retry-interval-in-seconds="10" 
        connection-leak-reclaim="false" 
        connection-leak-timeout-in-seconds="0" 
        connection-validation-method="auto-commit" 
        datasource-classname="com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource" 
        fail-all-connections="false" idle-timeout-in-seconds="300" 
        is-connection-validation-required="false" 
        is-isolation-level-guaranteed="true" 
        lazy-connection-association="false" 
        lazy-connection-enlistment="false" 
        match-connections="false" 
        max-connection-usage-count="0" 
        max-pool-size="32" 
        max-wait-time-in-millis="60000" 
        name="forcaVendasWebPool" 
        non-transactional-connections="false" 
        pool-resize-quantity="2" 
        res-type="javax.sql.ConnectionPoolDataSource" 
        statement-timeout-in-seconds="-1" 
        steady-pool-size="8" 
        validate-atmost-once-period-in-seconds="0" 
        wrap-jdbc-objects="false">

        <property name="URL" value="jdbc:mysql://IPdoMeuServidor:3306/planf571_PORTAL?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull"/>
        <property name="User" value="planf571_root"/>
        <property name="Password" value="minhaSenha"/>
    </jdbc-connection-pool>
</resources>
```

**HibernateUtil**

```
public class HibernateUtil {

    private static final SessionFactory factory = buildSessionFactory();

    public static SessionFactory getFactory() {
        return factory;
    }

    private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
        try {
            Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();
            StandardServiceRegistryBuilder serviceRegistryBuilder = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder();
            serviceRegistryBuilder.applySettings(configuration.getProperties());

            ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = serviceRegistryBuilder.build();

            System.out.println("Abre sessão Hibernate");
            SessionFactory session = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
            return session;

        } catch (HibernateException ex) {
            System.err.println("Criação da SessionFactory failed." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
    <display-name>Planfor - Força de Vendas</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>AutenticadorFVController</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>br.com.forcavendasweb.controller.AutenticadorFVController</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>ClientesFVController</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>br.com.forcavendasweb.controller.ClientesFVController</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>PedidosFVController</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>br.com.forcavendasweb.controller.PedidosFVController</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>TabelasFVController</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>br.com.forcavendasweb.controller.TabelasFVController</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <resource-ref>
        <res-ref-name>jdbc/forcaVendasWeb</res-ref-name>
        <res-type>javax.sql.ConnectionPoolDataSource</res-type>
        <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
        <res-sharing-scope>Shareable</res-sharing-scope>
    </resource-ref>
</web-app>
```

**Os erros**

```
Advertência: StandardWrapperValve[AutenticadorFVController]: PWC1406: Servlet.service() for servlet AutenticadorFVController threw exception
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.Table.indexes()[Ljavax/persistence/Index;
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.EntityBinder.processComplementaryTableDefinitions(EntityBinder.java:936)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindClass(AnnotationBinder.java:824)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processAnnotatedClassesQueue(Configuration.java:3790)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processMetadata(Configuration.java:3744)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1410)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1844)
    at br.com.portalserver.factory.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:30)
    at br.com.portalserver.factory.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:15)
    at br.com.portalserver.dao.UsuariosFVDAO.autenticarUsuarioFV(UsuariosFVDAO.java:237)
    at br.com.forcavendasweb.controller.AutenticadorFVController.doPost(AutenticadorFVController.java:62)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:688)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:770)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1550)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)



Advertência: 4ba4da36]-HelperThread-#0;|com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask@134e3b69 -- Acquisition Attempt Failed!!! Clearing pending acquires. While trying to acquire a needed new resource, we failed to succeed more than the maximum number of allowed acquisition attempts (30). Last acquisition attempt exception: 
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: User planf571_root already has more than 'max_user_connections' active connections
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor308.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:408)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:943)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3973)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3909)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:873)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(MysqlIO.java:1710)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1226)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2191)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2222)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2017)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:779)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor162.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:389)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:330)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnection(DriverManagerDataSource.java:146)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:195)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:184)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.acquireResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:200)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquire(BasicResourcePool.java:1086)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquireAndDecrementPendingAcquiresWithinLockOnSuccess(BasicResourcePool.java:1073)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$800(BasicResourcePool.java:44)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1810)
    at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:648)
```

Estou à mais de 10 dias tentando decifrar isto e não consigo chegar à lugar algum.
Por favor, se alguém puder me ajudar.

Comment: Tem duas exceções. Creio que a primeira é devido ao Glassfish 3.1 não suportar JPA 2.1, como o método `javax.persistence.Table.indexes()` só foi adicionado nesta versão da JPA, ocorre este erro. Um usuário no stackoverflow.com postou [esta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29416541) resposta com uma possível solução. Quanto a segunda, parece que você definiu o máximo de conexões no `glassfish-resources.xml` como 32, mas o usuário do banco de dados só tem permissão para criar 30.

Comment: Olá @felipe-marinho.  Quanto a questão dos usuários, foi resolvido.  A questão do JPA, infelizmente ainda não.  Vou fazer mais uns testes e posto a resposta.  Muito obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Pessoal, resolvi o problema atualizando o Glassfish para o 4.0.  Muito obrigado pela atenção de todos.

Answer (score 0):

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: User planf571_root already has more than 'max_user_connections' active connections
```

Aqui diz que o User que vc esta usando, esta no limite de conexões, veja as permissões dele no bancos e aumente a quantidade de conexões conforme vc usar

Comment: o problema da quantidade de usuários.  Infelizmente o outro problema nao consegui resolver ainda.  Muito obrigado.

Comment: qual servidor esta usando? AWS?